# System Variable missing for QTP?

Tags: operating-system, environment-variables, qtp

Anyone ever had this problem - I open QTP on my Primary machine and it tells me the resources are missing.  This is odd since all QTP files are stored on a central file server.  If I correct this it works fine.  But, I open QTP on my secondary machine where I run the tests after building them, and I get the same missing resources.  Opening the test on different machines and resetting the path to the resources is causing the missing resources.

I am guessing I am missing a system variable, but I am not sure what.  I tried looking at the two machine system variables, but nothing look obvious that it is pointing to the QTP files.

Note- this just started occurring when I got a new primary machine.  Unfortunately, I did not notice this until after they have already wiped my old machine.  Again, I would expect that I need something in the System's Environment Variables, but I am not sure what.

Any ideas?  Suggestions on something to read that might help?  The name of a good psychic to direct me in finding the answer?  :-)

Thanks,

Jamie

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by *If I correct this it works fine* but I sometime see problems with a network mapping going stale, in that case just accessing the remote drive (`cd /d x:`) or re-preforming the `net use` fixes the problem.